# nullpointer exception when trying to get extras from intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I created a very small app, which I based very closely on the tutorials that can be found over at google. There should be no problems, but now I am really stuck. I have two activities, a `MainActivity` and one that is called `HalleActivity`.

In `MainActivity.java` I have this:

```
public final static String EXTRA_ID = "com.fifaltra.kletterscore.ID";
java.util.ArrayList<Data> listItems=new java.util.ArrayList<Data>();
ArrayAdapter<Data> adapter;
private ListView mListView;
final Context context = this;
```

[...]

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            listItems.get(position).increaseCount();
            Collections.sort(listItems, Data.vergleichen());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, HalleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, listItems.get(position).getId());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

And in `HalleActivity.java` there is just this:

```
public class HalleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

   long id = extras.getLong(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID);
}
```

Now when I start this, as soon as I click on the item, the app crashes and the log contains the following:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{fifaltra.kletterscore/fifaltra.kletterscore.HalleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at fifaltra.kletterscore.HalleActivity.<init>(HalleActivity.java:11)
            at ...
```

Where line 11 is `Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();`. I have no idea what is going wrong here as I every example I found on the internet looked exactly like this, so I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `getIntent()` until the Activity has been initialized.  That's `onCreate`.  Before that, it returns null, so the call to intent.getExtra() NPEs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `.getStringExtra("com.fifaltra.kletterscore.ID");` instead of bundle.

Comment: But since id is a long, I thought that if anything I should do `long id = intent.getLongExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID, 0);`, and I also tried that, but with the same result.

Comment: Is your list which is put in 'extra' filled with some data?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I couldn't click on the item in the list. I also printed everything that's contained in the list element into the string that is displayed, so `id` also definitely contains some value.

Comment: `id` is returned by  `getId()`

Comment: I also did this as a test: `intent.putExtra("test", "testest");`, but it still crashed when trying to get the Bundle.

Comment: Can you even start this 'HalleActivity' without putting extras at all? Try this first, maybe extras even aren't problem...

Comment: If I comment out all the lines that are trying to access extras, it works fine (it's just the hello world template up till now)

Comment: I also tried accessing the test string like this `String s2 = intent.getStringExtra("test");` , to no avail